# If $span(X_1) \subset span(X_2)$ then their associated projectors are such that $ \mathbf{P_1} \cdot \mathbf{P_2} = \mathbf{P_1}$

Tags: matrices

how to prove $ \mathbf{P_1} \cdot \mathbf{P_X} = \mathbf{P_1}$ which
$\mathbf{P_X} \equiv \mathbf{X} \left(\mathbf{X}^\top  \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1}  \mathbf{X}^\top$
$ \mathbf{P_1}  \equiv  \mathbf{X_1} \left( {\mathbf{X_1}}^\top  \mathbf{X_1} \right)^{-1} {\mathbf{X_1}}^\top$ ?
besides,the space spanned by matrix X1 belongs to the space spanned by matrix X

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381651/305862 (the fact that it is in an Hilbert space is unimportant : it could have been settled in the $n$D space).

Answer (score 0):

Hint : First show that $P_X \cdot P_1=P_1$ then use symmetry of projection matrices to find the equality you want.

You will also need that $Hy=y$ $\forall y \in Im(H) $ when H is a projection matrix.